# How to format a string substitute, or a text line, in Vim?

Tags: vim, gvim, find-and-replace, text-formatting

Is it possible to format the replacement string when substituting a match with `Vim`?

Say I have a file with a 2-column table, where the entries in each row are separated with a space. The entries (and the lines) are not fixed width. I want to format the table such that the 2nd column items are all justified, by adding the appropriate amount of spaces.

For example, the given table:

```
A aa
BBBB bbb
CC c
```

What I want:

```
A      aa
BBBB   bbb
CC     c
```

(Please note that tabs are not a solution here.)

The `Vim` command may look something like:

```
:0,$ s/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\1(******N)\2/
```

and the `(******N)` should be replaced with the formatting code to put the 2nd element at the Nth character position.

**UPDATE 1**: So, Vim has the `printf()` function. Can it be used directly from the command prompt for that purpose, or does it have to be included in a Vim script, with an explicit loop running through all lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to try one of the align plugins on vim.org. I use the most popular one by Dr. Campbell: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294

That aside, though, yes, you can call Vim functions from a substitute command, but the drawback is that the *entire* replacement pattern has to be an expression.  See "`:help sub-replace-expression`" and "`:help submatch()`".  For example, if we wanted to replace a matched pattern with a letter count:

```
:%s/pattern/\=len(submatch(0))/g
```

So your idea of using printf() would work:

```
:%s/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\=printf('%-7s %-7s',submatch(1),submatch(2))/
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify your system but, on UNIX-like systems, you can use the `column` command as a filter:

```
:%!column -t
```

Reference:

```
:help filter
$ man column
```

Comment: Thanks. It is Windows. +1 - i assume it works on linux, and for thinking "out of the box" ;-)

Comment: Only a windows user could call that "thinking out of the box".

Comment: it was meant to be a little joke, referring to "going out of the Vim realm to the OS shell for doing the task". Note the ";-)". I am a Linux user as well, BTW...